# Allowing partially trusted callers security exception is been thrown althought running on Full trust mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, asp.net-2.0, medium-trust

While developing using ASP.net 2.0 (C#) and NHibernate 2.1.0
I am getting the error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
```

This error is been thrown **only** in the production server (a web hosting company) and in my development environment everything is fine.

I also ran this code below on the production server to see the Code Access Security (CAS) level and got **True** from:

```
System.Security.SecurityManager.IsGranted(new AspNetHostingPermission(AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted))
```

so I can assume I am currently running in a full trusted mode..

After reading some articles about this kind of problem (not specifically for NHibernate)
I understood that I need to add

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]
```

to my AssebmlyInfo.cs file.

My question is:
Is there a way to solve this exception without having to edit the **NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll**'s AssmeblyInfo.cs ? Is there something that can be configured in the web.config to allow this kind of action?

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: In my attempts to get something running on medium trust locally with NHibernate 2.1.1 with LinFu I ran into the same issue.

I switched my proxy to Castle and used the dynamicproxy that is found in NHibernate Proxy generators and I can run medium trust locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the steps called out here?

[Using NHibernate in a Medium Trust web environment](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/run-in-medium-trust.aspx)